# Should I call `vkMapMemory` each time I write to a buffer?

Tags: memory, memory-management, vulkan

Are there any benefits to using a single `vkMapMemory`, a `memset`s for each write, and a single `vkUnmapMemory` as opposed to using a `vkMapMemory`, `memset`, and `vkUnmapMemory` for each write to a buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is beneficial to map only once. `vkMapMemory` likely needs to do some system calls, so it is not free.

Authoritative quote, e.g. https://developer.samsung.com/game/usage#buffermanagement:

> Frequent Map/Unmap calls should be avoided.