# Do I need to memory map/unmap a buffer every time the content of the buffer changes?

Tags: vulkan

I'm doing a Vulkan project that renders into an outgoing stream instead of presenting it (no swapchain et al): the rendered image is copied to another image (`vkCmdCopyImage`) then that later image is memory mapped (`vkMapMemory`), data is copied somewhere else then it is unmapped (`vkUnmapMemory`). This is happing at every frame. Is there a way to map the (second) image once, enter the main loop (render a frame at each cycle) then unmap it as part of the application clean-up ?
I tried this but it looks like whenever something is copied to the image, the earlier mapping doesn't work and it has to be unmapped and mapped again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I call \`vkMapMemory\` each time I write to a buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118275/should-i-call-vkmapmemory-each-time-i-write-to-a-buffer)

Answer (score 4):

It is never necessary in Vulkan to unmap memory you have mapped. Even deleting the memory implicitly unmaps it.

However, it *is* necessary to synchronize access to that memory properly. For modifying an image on the GPU, using execution&memory dependencies to ensure the availability and visibility of the GPU modifications to the host, events that the CPU can wait on/test to ensure that the modification is visible, and if the memory is not host-coherent you will need to invoke `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` to ensure visibility of such changes to the host.

Comment: It's als not necessary to unmap memory explicitly when you're freeing it according to vkFreeMemory specification. But yes. For the opposite (CPU writes, GPU reads) case, the respective function to call for non-HOST_COHERENT memory is vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges (don't forget to align the flush/invalidate offset and size to nonCoherentAtomSize).

Comment: Also, if data read by the GPU within a submission is written by the CPU after the call to vkQueueSubmit (if you're explicitly waiting for the write to be done via a VkEvent on the GPU), you need to transition the range from VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT/VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT after waiting before reading the new data — this makes it `visible` to the GPU (flushing/coherent write only makes it `available`). For the usual case (writing everything needed before the vkQueueSubmit), this barrier is implicit in vkQueueSubmit and is not required.